# how to reach the network from CentOS vm in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a CentOS 5.6 VM set up in virtualbox running on Windows 7.  I had the network configured to run on DHCP when the VM was built, and it worked fine with a public internet connection.

However, I now have moved the VM to a private internal network, and have set a static IP address, gateway, and DNS server.  The VM cannot reach any other machines in the private network, nor can any other machines reach it (either by hostname or ip address). The DNS has been configured to include this host.

I need to figure out how to configure the VM to behave as though it was just another machine on the network.

Comment: I think you have to use the NAT interface of virtualbox to achieve this. Where did you set the static IP? Within CentOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the guest ethernet card in either NAT or bridged mode. If you only need outgoing network connectivity (for web browsing, etc), NAT is fine. However, if you want to run services on your CentOS (such as ssh, etc) that you wish to access from other hosts on the network, you'll need to use bridged mode; this will allow the guest system to appear to be just another machine on the network.